# Fix for CRC Error

Tags: ssd, crc, recovery

I have an SSD with a CRC Error. When I connect the drive to the PC, it does not appear as a drive (with associated drive letter) so I cannot run CHKDSK against it but it does appear in Disk Management. When I open Disk Management, I get the Initialise Disk window appear asking if I want to select GPT or MBR for the drive. Whichever I select fails and the drive is unuseable.
It's selectable in DISKPART and I can run the `clean` command against it but I cannot format it or create a partition.

Is there any way I can recover this drive please?

Comment: You have done everything possible. The disk seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done everything possible to get the drive working in Windows. The fact your efforts have been unsuccessful confirm the drive has failed. Even if it spontaneously started working at some point, you couldn't trust the drive with any data.

Your disk has failed and it needs to be replaced.